# Некорректная работа многопоточного quicksort-а

Tags: c++, многопоточность, qsort

Пытаюсь запустить пример многопоточной быстрой сортировки из книги Энтони Уильямса - "Параллельное программирование на С++ в действии. 2012". Получаю вот такое exception-ы:

> what():  empty stack
>
> terminate called recursively
>
> terminate called recursively
>
> terminate called recursively

либо

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'empty_stack'
>
> what():  empty stack
>
> Process finished with exit code 134 (interrupted by signal 6: SIGABRT)

Ниже приводится код приложения, единственное различие заключается в том, что я не использую `boost::shared_ptr`, а заменил их на `std::shared_ptr`.

```
#include <iostream>

#include <list>

#include <future>

#include <stack>

#include <thread>

//#include <exception>

// #include <mutex>

// #include <memory>

// #include <chrono>

#include <vector>

#include <algorithm>



struct empty_stack : std::exception {
    const char *what() const throw() {
        return "empty stack";
    }
};


template<typename T>

class thread_safe_stack //реализация потокобезопасного стэка
{
private:
    std::stack<T> data;
    mutable std::mutex m;
public:
    thread_safe_stack() {}

    thread_safe_stack(const thread_safe_stack &other) {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(other.m);
        data = other.data;
    }

thread_safe_stack &operator=(const thread_safe_stack &) = delete;

void push(T new_value) {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m);
    data.push(std::move(new_value));
}

std::shared_ptr<T> pop() {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m);
    if (data.empty()) throw empty_stack();
    std::shared_ptr<T> const res(
            std::make_shared<T>(std::move(data.top())));
    data.pop();
    return res;
}

void pop(T &value) {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m);
    if (data.empty()) throw empty_stack();
    value = std::move(data.top());
    data.pop();
}

bool empty() const {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m);
    return data.empty();
}
};

template<typename T>
struct sorter { // класс sorter объединяет стек неотсортированных блоков
    struct chunk_to_sort {
        std::list<T> data;
        std::promise<std::list<T>> promise;
};

thread_safe_stack<chunk_to_sort> chunks;
std::vector<std::thread> threads; 
unsigned const max_thread_count;
std::atomic<bool> end_of_data;

sorter() :
        max_thread_count(std::thread::hardware_concurrency() - 1),
        end_of_data(false) {}

~sorter() {
    end_of_data = true;
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < threads.size(); ++i) {
        threads[i].join();
    }
}

void try_sort_chunk() {
    std::shared_ptr<chunk_to_sort> chunk = chunks.pop();
    if (chunk) {
        sort_chunk(chunk);
    }
}

std::list<T> do_sort(std::list<T> &chunk_data)
{

    {
        if (chunk_data.empty()) {
            return chunk_data;
        }
    }

    std::list<T> result;
    result.splice(result.begin(), chunk_data, chunk_data.begin());
    T const &partition_val = *result.begin();
    typename std::list<T>::iterator divide_point =
            std::partition(chunk_data.begin(), chunk_data.end(),
                           [&](T const &val) { return val < partition_val; });

    chunk_to_sort new_lower_chunk;
    new_lower_chunk.data.splice(new_lower_chunk.data.end(),
                                chunk_data, chunk_data.begin(),
                                divide_point);

    std::future<std::list<T> > new_lower =
            new_lower_chunk.promise.get_future();
    chunks.push(std::move(new_lower_chunk));
    if (threads.size() < max_thread_count) {
        threads.push_back(std::thread(&sorter<T>::sort_thread, this));
    }

    std::list<T> new_higher(do_sort(chunk_data));

    result.splice(result.end(), new_higher);
    while (new_lower.wait_for(std::chrono::seconds(0)) !=
           std::future_status::ready) {
        try_sort_chunk();
    }

    result.splice(result.begin(), new_lower.get());
    return result;
}

void sort_chunk(std::shared_ptr<chunk_to_sort > const& chunk)
{
    chunk->promise.set_value(do_sort(chunk->data));
}

void sort_thread()
{
    while(!end_of_data)
    {
        try_sort_chunk();
        std::this_thread::yield();
    }
}

};

template<typename T>
std::list<T> parallel_quick_sort(std::list<T> input) {
if (input.empty()) {
    return input;
}
sorter<T> s;
return s.do_sort(input);
}


int main() {
std::list<int> cocks;
for(int i = 0; i<100; ++i){
    cocks.push_back(std::rand()%100);
}
for(auto i:cocks ) {
    std::cout << i << " ";
}

std::list<int> new_cocks = parallel_quick_sort(cocks);


//    for(auto i:new_cocks ) {
//        std::cout << i;
//    }


return 0;
}
```

Почему приложение падает с такими ошибками? Буду благодарен за объяснения.

Comment: Слишком много кода. Судя по тексту, что Вы привели, приложение падает из-за исключения, которую выброшена Вашим кодом в виду пустоты стека. Причину нужно искать с отладчиком в руках.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по строкам

```
void try_sort_chunk() {
    std::shared_ptr<chunk_to_sort> chunk = chunks.pop();
    if (chunk) {
        sort_chunk(chunk);
    }
}
```

создается впечатление, что эта функция явно не ожидает, что в случае пустого стека, нужно бросать исключение. Она явно пытается проверить, прибежало ли там что то. Поэтому, pop у стека должен возвращать nullptr, если стек пуст. Исправим

Так как функций две, исправим обе, на всякий случай. Также, я сильно не заморачивался и просто создаю пустой `shared_ptr`.

```
std::shared_ptr<T> pop() {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m);
    if (data.empty())
      return std::shared_ptr<T>();
    std::shared_ptr<T> const res(
            std::make_shared<T>(std::move(data.top())));
    data.pop();
    return res;
}

void pop(T &value) {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m);
    if (data.empty()) return std::shared_ptr<T>();
    value = std::move(data.top());
    data.pop();
}
```

И конечно стоит не забыть раскоментировать вывод отсортированной последовательности и добавить туда пробелов. А то можно долго удивляться выводу. Где то так, например:

```
for(auto i:new_cocks ) {
    std::cout << i << " ";
}
std::cout << std::endl;
```

После этого можно компилировать и запускать. Оно уже не падает и выводит отсортированную последовательность.

---

Но меня смутило то, что в коде есть гонки. На них ругается gcc. Например, здесь

```
if (threads.size() < max_thread_count) {
    threads.push_back(std::thread(&sorter<T>::sort_thread, this));
}
```

Но этот вопрос нужно отдельно исследовать.

Answer (score 0):

У вас очень плохой код. В многопоточном приложение так нельзя писать. Не понятно кто и в какой момент запускает потоки, в do_sort вы передаете объект, который может быть модифицирован, а мьютекса для него нет. Возможно ваша имлементация как-то гарантирует, что этот объект не будут трогать в двух потоках одновременно, но понять по коду где эти гарантии не возможно.

Все что удалось понять, это у вас переменная threads не прикрыта. У вас удинственный инстанс sorter одновремнно "работает" с этой переменной в нескольких потоках.

Строка: threads.push_back(std::thread(&sorter::sort_thread, this));

1-ый поток выполнил "std::thread(&sorter::sort_thread, this)". В 1-ом  потоке получили новый объект std::stread, НО! второй поток уже создан в системе и в любой момент может получить управлени.

1-ый поток пытается сделелать push_back в вектор и в этот момент происходит переключение, 2-ой поток начал исполнятся и дошел до do_sort а затем и до threads и начал его модифицировать. Итог - гонка с первым потоком за push_back

Кстати на if(thread.size()...) тоже может быть гонка.

Но это не единственное место, я пробовал поставить там мьютекс, но он не спасает, надо дальше разбираться, но прорываться через вашу логику очень не хочется....

Если вы решаете реальную прикладную задачу, то лучше сразу разбить список на N частей, размера не меньше M и сортировать эту часть в одном потоке. Для объектов, которые сравниваются по int'у, значение M должно быть 1k-64k и более. После сортировки всех часле, отдельно запустить слияние, если частей много, то в несколько потоков, если мало, то в одном.

Comment: почти весь код, который приведет в вопросе написан Энтони Уильямсом. А он как бы известный спец в многопоточном программировании

Comment: @KoVadim, а можно ссылку на эти исходники, чтоб понять что там от автора, а что от "спеца". Боюсь, чтоб не получилось как анекдоте про Рабиновича, который соседу оперу напел.

Comment: я сверял. там стек от -автора- спеца. Он в листинге 3.5. сортировка - 8.1 https://www.manning.com/books/c-plus-plus-concurrency-in-action

Comment: Так к stack'у притензий нет, там все прямоленейно. "Плохой код" это про do_sort и далее. Я посмотрел вашу ссылу, так вот, там есть очешь хороши примеры, как запускать задачи в других потоках. Как передавать контекст и как получать результаты. Так вот, тут автор очень далек от тех рекомендаций.

Comment: @KoVadim, А есть прямая ссылка на листинг 3.5, что-то не могу найти полной имплементации

Comment: эм... зайти по моей ссылке, слева найти download, скачать архив и ... PROFIT!!!